# Why is Glimpse still running?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I made glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy Off but it still shows an error like this

```
Unable to define EFProfiledDbProviderServices class of type 'GlimpseDbProviderServices'. Please check that your web.config defines a <DbProviderFactories> section underneath <system.data>
```

shouldn't glimpse be out of asp.net mvc pipeline after making it off?

Update :

I also commented all the glimpse related part in web.config but I still get the same above error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that even when you disable Glimpse completely through the web.config, which makes sure Glimpse is not collecting any information during request processing, that there are still assemblies, like `Glimpse.Ado` and `Glimpse.EF*`, that have a `PreApplicationStartMethod` attribute defined, which means that some hooks are being put in place, even though they are not going to do anything when requests are being processed.

The solution is to remove the `Glimpse.EF*` assembly, and maybe the `Glimpse.Ado` assembly as well, from you bin directory.

Comment: follow-up question, how do you automate something like that? using MS WebDeploy?

Comment: yes, you can use web.config transformations to remove Glimpse specific config from a release web.config and you can even remove files from being deployed as well, like those `Glimpse.EF*` and `Glimpse.Ado` assemblies (check [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx) on how to do that. __Tip__ exclude file bin\Glimpse.Ado.dll and bin\Glimpse.EFx.dll)